# Can I Edit the ProcessDefintion.xml during runtime in jBPM project?

Tags: java, jbpm

My problem is to make some dynamic transitions using a User interface, so I want the process definition file to be created and altered during runtime.

But, I am not sure whether is it possible. As everytime I have to deploy the process definition whenever I change it. So, how can I make it dynamically changing.

Suggestions?

I am using jBPM 3.2.x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to deploy your processdefinition each time it is changed.

Dynamically you can do it like...

modification-->deploying--> automatically refer latest version available.

But it will not be applicable for process already started.